# How to add epoch time in terms of seconds in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add epoch time in terms of seconds in dart 
for eg:

```
static int TIMESTAMP = new DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
```

But I don't want it in microseconds I want the timestamp in epoch seconds format.

Answer (score 15):

The Dart `DateTime` object only exposes `SinceEpoch` functionality for milliseconds and microseconds, but gettings seconds instead is as simple as:

```
int secondsSinceEpoch = date.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ Duration.millisecondsPerSecond;
```

where `Duration.millisecondsPerSecond` is just a long way of writing `1000`.

Going the other direction is equally simple:

```
var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(secondsSinceEpoch * 1000);
```

Comment: One of the best Dart developer out there. Thanks Irn for all your answers :)

Comment: :D sometimes I doubt about my mind which could not handle simple problems

Answer (score 1):

Let assume the `epoch = 1653760800` that's in seconds, then to covert to a human date in dart:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
var dt =DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1653760800 *1000)).toString();
print(dt);
}
```

Output:

```
28/05/2022
```